# Laravel 5.6 - Erro ao passar 2 parâmetros na url

Tags: laravel-5, url, url-amigável

Olá, estou tentando passar 2 parametros para o meu controller usando url e estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: teacher.average_faults] [URI:
>   professor/average-faults/{team}{matter}].

minha view esta assim:

```
<a href="{{route('teacher.average_faults',[$team->id,$matter->id])}}"></a>
```

meu controller:

```
public function closureTeacherAverage_Faults($team, $matter){
    $verify = Closure::find(1);
    $team = Team::find($team);
    $matter = Matter::find($matter);

    $students_ids = DB::table('student_team')->select('student_id')->where('team_id','=',$team->id)->pluck('student_id');

    $students = [];
    foreach ($students_ids as $value) {            
        $students[] = montar(Student::find($value));
    }

    return view('closure.averages_faults',compact('verify','students','matter'));
}
```

minha rota web está assim:

```
Route::get('professor/average-faults/{team}{matter}',   ['as' => 'teacher.average_faults', 'uses' => 'Employee\ClosureController@closureTeacherAverage_Faults']);
```

Se alguém puder ajuda, agradeço desde já.

Comment: Acredito que terá complicações utilizando a url nesse formato, mas pode fazer do seguinte modo:
`<a href="{{ route('teacher.average_faults',['team' => $team->id, 'matter' => $matter->id])}}"></a>`

Comment: Porque não usa um separador na definição da sua rota?

`Route::get('professor/average-faults/{team}/{matter})`

Comment: fiz oq vc falou mas continua com o mesmo erro de missing parameters... =/
sim eu tmb modifiquei colocando um separador como vc mostrou acima.
erro --> return new static("Missing required parameters for [Route: {$route->getName()}] [URI: {$route->uri()}].");

Comment: consegui consertar, deixando um parametro como principal e outro como opcional.
assim--> Route::get('listMatters/{team}/{matter?}
encontrei a resposta completa aqui --> https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-pass-two-arguments-to-controller